# Append the dragged file to div

Tags: javascript

In my code , I need to append the dragged files from the desktop to a list. For that I understand I need to get event.dataTransfer('Text'), but it returns a empty string . Any help is appreciated

```js
function myfk(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();

}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  alert(String(data));

  var x = document.getElementById("list")

  //x.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;height:500px;background:red" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="myfk(event)">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried and get an error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFk is not defined`

Comment: Now try and see , I editted the question

Comment: What you're doing is you're retrieving data from a drag event, not a file upload event. I'd suggest getting a look at this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications. There are several examples which will help you :)

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for the link. I followed that tutorial and now it is working . Thank you so much salixor